# Matching Mentees and Mentors

Tags: excel

I'm currently trying to match mentors and mentees. I have three sheets in total:

1. Mentees
2. Mentors
3. MenteesXMentors: this is the sheet where I'm looking to get best possible matches based on the program of both the mentors and mentees. i.e in my case Henry Paul and Josie Sterla should be the possible matches

I tried to use the Index match formula, and it only displays the title of the column. Not sure if there is any other formula that can be applied in this case.

**Here is the mentees sheet:**

[image: Mentees]

**Here is the mentors sheet:**

[image: Mentors]

**Here is the MenteesXMentors sheet where matches will take place:**
[image: MenteesXMentors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if there are say 5 mentors and 7 mentees in the same program?
What happens if there are programs that have mentees but not mentors?
It's difficult to see how you could program a definitive solution, but you can get Excel to group things for you to use your judgement to complete the process.
Put Mentors and Mentees in one table, with a column saying "Mentee" or "Mentor".
Then use a Pivot Table.
You can get a result like this:
[image]
from which (if appropriate) you can also see that you could match Tom with Jessica because at least the Faculty matches even though the program doesn't.

Here's an introduction to Pivot Tables that looks better than the current Microsoft one.https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2016/intro-to-pivottables/1/

If you are happy with totals at the top, then it will look slightly different - if you want totals at the bottom, then once you have created it, right-click anywhere in the Pivot Table | Display | tick Classic PivotTable layout...

And here's an image of the what fields I dragged where to get the result above: [image: Fields for Pivot Table].

Comment: Is there a way you could show me how you created the pivot table? I'm new to it and never used it before. Thank you

Comment: Yes, added to existing answer.